# jQuery scrollTop animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

css

```
.head { 
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 76px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
 }
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  const height = $(document).scrollTop();
  console.log(height);
  if (height > 0) {
    console.log("no 0");
    $("#tt-body-index .head").animate(
      {
        marginTop: 0,
      },
      1000,
      "swing"
    );
  } else if (height === 0) {
    console.log("0");
    $("#tt-body-index .head").animate(
      {
        marginTop: -76,
      },
      1000,
      "swing"
    );
  }
});
```

I'm writing a script using jQuery.
When scrolling starts .head appears and tries to make scrollTop 0 disappear.
.head appearing is good, but when scrollTop is zero, it doesn't become `marginTop: -76`.

Comment: Head must be position: fixed in order to work as expected

Comment: head has already position

.head {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 76px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS transitions and animation whenever possible which is more smooth compared to jquery animations, this can be done using css transition check the below code. Also, one thing you need to trigger scroll on page load in case if the browser scrolls the page to some part from the cache.

CSS

```
.head { 
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: -80px;
    height: 76px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: aqua;
    transition: top 1s;
}
body.showHeader .head{
    top: 0px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    const height = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(height);
    if (height < 76) {                    
        $('body').removeClass('showHeader')
    } else  {
        $('body').addClass('showHeader')
    }
}).scroll();
```